# VB.Net 'Overridable' is not valid on a member variable declaration

Tags: c#, vb.net, variables, overriding

I'm using several code converters which produce the same VB.Net coding but VS will not except this line of code:

```
Private Overridable m_Products As ICollection(Of Product)
```

VS states:

'Overridable' is not valid on a member variable declaration.

The C# coding is from a tutorial on the ASP.Net web site at:

```
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer
```

VS also states I should remove the Overridable keyword. If I do that, will I break something in the tutorial?

This is the C# coding I'm running through the converters:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Product Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the result of the conversion:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace WingtipToys.Models
Public Class Category
    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> _
    Public Property CategoryID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_CategoryID
        End Get
        Set
            m_CategoryID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_CategoryID As Integer

    <Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name := "Name")> _
    Public Property CategoryName() As String
        Get
            Return m_CategoryName
        End Get
        Set
            m_CategoryName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_CategoryName As String

    <Display(Name := "Product Description")> _
    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return m_Description
        End Get
        Set
            m_Description = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Description As String

    Public Overridable Property Products() As ICollection(Of Product)
        Get
            Return m_Products
        End Get
        Set
            m_Products = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Overridable m_Products As ICollection(Of Product)
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: See vcsjones answer - the problem is that the properties should be converted to VB auto properties.  Unless your target is VB2008, the converter should not have created explicit backing fields. For 2008 and earlier, remove 'Overridable' on the backing fields.

Comment: I'm using VS 2012. I will first try as you suggested and see if it works. Thanks everyone for the quick replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields cannot be overridable, but a property can. I'm not sure why the converter created a backing field at all, you can use VB.NET's auto properties (If you are using Visual Studio 2010 or greater). Try this:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace WingtipToys.Models
Public Class Category
    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> _
    Public Property CategoryID As Integer

    <Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name := "Name")> _
    Public Property CategoryName As String


    <Display(Name := "Product Description")> _
    Public Property Description As String         

    Public Overridable Property Products As ICollection(Of Product)
End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make a *Property* `Overridable`, but not a *Field*:

```vb
' The property here is fine to be overridable
Public Overridable Property Products() As ICollection(Of Product)
    Get
        Return m_Products
    End Get
    Set
        m_Products = Value
    End Set
End Property

' The backing field cannot be
Private m_Products As ICollection(Of Product)
```

Derived classes can reimplement and override the property, which may cause the backing field to be unused, but they can't override a field directly.